# Validate models on application startup

Tags: python, django, django-models

Question: Is there a way to fetch models from DB at startup and crash if some validation checks fail?

Explanation:

I've got the following model (simplified):

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    related = models.ForeignKey('other_app.Model')
    service_classes = models.CharField(...)

    def validate(self):
        valid = # checks service_classes against settings.SERVICE_CLASSES - see below
        if not self.valid:
            raise ValidationException("invalid")
```

`service_classes` contains a comma-separated list of service classes identifiers, i.e. `service_class1,service_class2`.

Service classes basically look like that:

```
# module service.py
ServiceClass1(object):
    ID = 'service_class1'

ServiceClass2(object):
    ID = 'service_class2'
```

Django settings file contains a list of paths to service classes that are enabled for this instance:

```
SERVICE_CLASSES = [
    'service.ServiceClass1',
    'service.ServiceClass2'
]
```

However, since `SERVICE_CLASSES` can be modified after `Configuration` models already created, they might become out of sync, and bad things could happen if `Configuration.service_classes` contain IDs of classes not found in `SERVICE_CLASSES`. So, essentially, what I want to do is to execute the following code at application startup:

```
for config in Configuration.models.all():
    config.validate() # and let it throw Exception to fail fast
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) suggests using `AppConfig.ready` for startup initialization code, but with an explicit instruction to avoid accessing DB in any way there. I've tried that anyway and it crashed with `OperationalError` - most likely the DB is not ready by that time, since it is executed before syncdb have a chance to create a database (not sure about that though).

I've tried placing it in models.py - crashes with `ValueError: Related model 'other_app.Model' cannot be resolved` - and it looks like it is totally right, since that app is not configured yet when `models.py` is processed.

Comment: All of this sounds like its covering up for lack of data migration, unit testing, and concrete deployment strategies

Comment: @Sayse It is quite the opposite - 98% test coverage, automated deployment, CI build, etc. The reason to add this is to fail fast if, against all precautions, erroneous update is still performed.

Comment: @Sayse also, if you could enlighten me how do you fix this with data migration, I would be very grateful. Note that we're not trying to change something right now - it is more of a safety switch if someone really messes up the deployment later.

Comment: Well I'd imagine the only time a model would fall into an invalid state is if you've modified a model, but not updated existing entries to use this new state. A data migration would be used to make sure these are all updated, you could also provide a reverse data migration so that if something erroneous did happen then you can revert back to a valid state before the migration was applied. If all your other captcha's didn't stop an invalid state, what makes you think a validate function would? :)

Comment: @Sayse I see you refuse to read the question and understand what I mean. :) There are *two* ways for model to become out of sync with settings: if model is changed, and if settings are changed. For model changes, I have that validation method called from `clean_fields`, so it prevents such kinds of model changes. What I'm trying to achieve now is to protect the app from settings changes - by failing startup if any of the `Configuration` models have service_class IDs of classes deleted form configuration. Does that make sense now? :)

Comment: @Sayse and failing to start the app would fail autodeploy, or be noticed by DevOps (for manual deploy). Anyway, the problem will be noticed at deployment time, not in runtime, when first clients hit the misisng service class.

Comment: My issue is I hate introducing tasks into the start up since this would be a fail safe against something that should have been updated when the setting is changed, resulting in a longer boot up time and potentially down time. Maybe not as verbose, but having a comment above that setting detailing that any changes need a data migration applied (even make a common function to be included in a data migration) would mean that validation of this setting is (should?) only ever done when a change is actually made

Comment: @Sayse I'm not an owner of this code, and I've been asked to do the startup validation. So, this meta-discussion ("why would you do that?") is fruitless anyway :)